# Braid server not finding corda jar files

Tags: kotlin, blockchain, corda, braid

I am trying to connect my braid server with the local corda node that i have. 
The node is working and i am able to connect to it through terminal 
[image]

when i try to connect the braid server to its not able to see it.

[image]

The program argument that i am using for braid server is as follow :`localhost:10006 user1 test 10200 3 “/Desktop/work/sample/corda/blockchain/m-cordapp/build/nodes/Owner/cordapps”`

Braid server terminal output log.

[image]

Any help is really apreciated.

Comment: Can you post more output from the Braid Server terminal? What you shared is not enough to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @AdelRustum thank you for your comment, i have updated the question with the output

Comment: Thanx, to confirm that you provided the correct path to the CorDapp folder inside Program Arguments, open `localhost:10200` in your browser and scroll down to cordapps; you should see your custom flows there. Btw, the double quotes that you're using might be the problem `“ ”`, use this instead `" "`.

Comment: @AdelRustum thank you for help. the " " was causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `“ ”` with `" "` in your path to CorDapps folder.